# Working with IE but not with chrome

Tags: javascript

Hi below is the javascript code that iam using to display an image in webpage.

```
  <a href="/LogoSnapShot/LogoSnapShot_nonjs.html" target="_new" onclick="return    OpenLogoSnapShot();">
  <script language="JavaScript">
  function altimg(sourceimg) {
  var img_with_logo=sourceimg.src;
  sourceimg.src=img_with_logo.substring(0,img_with_logo.search("BUYL")+4)+".jpg";
  sourceimg.onerror=null;
  }
  </script>
  <img id=prodImg name=ProdImage1 id=ProdImage1   src="http://ocs.landsend.com/OCS/corpsales/images/prod/17/67/176819DTKBUYL.jpg" onError="altimg(this);" width=250 height=250 alt="" border="0">
  </a>
```

'-' symbol is being displayed beside the image in chrome but it is fine in IE. Can anyone help me with it?

Comment: Sorry, what do u mean by console.. Iam new to this

Comment: how do you mean not working? i get picture in chrome. What is suppose to happen?

Comment: he means console in Chrome development tool (F12->Console)

Comment: Hit shift+ctrl+j for the console in Chrome. Quick tip...The `<script>` tag shouldn't use the `language` attribute anymore, but the `type="text/javascript"` attribute instead.

Comment: start by fixing your HTML... it is not valid.

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden) http://assets.pinterest.com/js/pinit.js
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'src' of null ProductDisplay:3112
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden) http://assets.pinterest.com/images/PinExt.png
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)

Comment: iam getting the above errors in console